# Spring 4.2 dispatcher servlet 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I created a application using spring `4.2.2.RELEASE` hibernate `5.0.2.Final` and deployed this application to jboss as 7.1.1 successfully. I enabled log level DEBUG so I can see what is happening and as per the logs the application is deployed successfully.

The name of the war file is `mycompany.war` so it is deployed at context path `/mycompany`.

I have a controller class like below

```
@RestController
public class AbcController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/campaigns", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
    public Campaign addCampaign(@RequestBody Campaign campaign) throws ServiceException {
        return campaignService.addCampaign(campaign);
    }
}
```

Now when I used postman to send the request to `localhost:8080/mycompany/campaigns` I am getting 404 error with below debug logs

```
04:30:18,975 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing POST request for [/mycompany/campaigns]
04:30:18,975 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/mycompany/campaigns] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
04:30:18,976 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Successfully completed request
```

Below is the `web.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Below is application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany"/>

    <bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/jpa-persistence.xml"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MainPU" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
</beans>
```

Why I am facing this issue ? I checked the complete logs there is no exception no error in the logs. Also I can see that my controllers are getting initialised by spring.

Comment: Turn on Spring logs at INFO level and check what request handlers are registered.

Comment: I suspect the problem comes from the context root of your web application.  How did you and what have you set for the webapp context root? In JBoss, by a brief check in google, seems depends on your EAR's `application.xml`, `WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml` or the WAR file name.  Make sure it the former 2 do not exists so that your context root is really your WAR name.

Comment: Oh, found another issue: I believe you suppose to have `<mvc:annotation-driven>` in your app context xml but seems I cannot see it.

Comment: @AdrianShum I had to add <mvc:annotation-driven>. Now it works but isn't this the auto behaviour ?

Comment: No it is not, at least not in your case :)

Comment: If that's the solution, then I will add that as an answer

Comment: You can try adding @ComponentScan above main class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in your application context XML.  It is required to allow, for example, request mapping using annotations.